# PHP Runs on Terminal but Web Page is Blank

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using PHP to connect to a locally hosted MySQL database, and displaying the results on a web page. My code goes like this:

```
  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Phone Number Leak!</h1>
    <p class="lead">P<?php echo "phone numbers leaked from Twitter"; ?></p>

<div style = "height:100vh;">
<?php

    error_reporting(-1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo "Hello";

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'twitter_phone');
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    echo "Connection established";
    $r2 = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from phone2");

    //echo "<table border = '1'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r2))
    {
        echo $row['author'];
        echo "<tr> <td>Checking ... </td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['tweet'] . "</td><td>" . $row['author'] . "</td><td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
    echo "</table>";    
?>
</div>
<!--</table>-->
  </div>

</div><!-- /.container -->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run this in the terminal as `php index1.php`, I see that it has fetched all the data from the tables, and it generates appropriate HTML code. But when I view it on the web page, I can't see anything. In fact, when I look at the source code, it ends after `<div style = "height:100vh;">
    Hello`
The HTML tags that follow the PHP section don't show up either. Error reporting also does nothing - all I get is a blank page with only the bits before the PHP code starts, and this last Hello message.

A simple `echo` command works, so it isn't a problem with the PHP setup either, right? So what's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_connect_error()` when you use `mysql`? Use instead `mysqli` everywhere, because `mysql` is decrepcated.

Comment: I've tried `mysql` as well. I'll change the code to reflect that. It still has the same problem.

Comment: Can you confirm that the version of PHP used via web server has mysqli enabled?  This can be different than version of PHP used for command line.

Comment: Well, turned out it wasn't enabled. But I had installed it. So `sudo service apache2 restart` and then refreshing the page did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding this line `var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'));`, I found out that mysqli was not enabled.

I did have the required packages though, so turns out I only had to do `sudo service apache2 restart`. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no function in PHP which is `mysql_connect_errno()` but `mysql_errno`
2. use `mysql_error()` to replace `mysqli_connect_error()`
3. Please align to use mysql_* function or mysqli_* function, there are different
4. Suggest using mysqli_* functions, because mysql_* functions are decrepcated.

Comment: I'd already tried `mysqli`, and I overlooked #2. Thanks for that. But the problem remains, even though I've changed it to `mysqli` everywhere.

Comment: Add `var_dump($con);die();` before the line of `mysqli_query()`

Comment: I've solved the problem. I'll post the answer here. Thanks anyway :)